# Yahoo YQL text size limits

Tags: php, yahoo, yql

I'm trying to use Yahoo Content Analysis on three simple texts.

As it is works but if i increase the string length in substr commands i get:

```
{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Unknown error","status":"500"}}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? According to the documentation the api should accept much larger strings.

Also i can't figure out why the limit is different per string. Any ideas?

Here's my code

```
<?php

/**
* Function to use Yahoo to analyse some simple text
* @param String $text
* @param String $format
* @return String $content
*/
function yahoo_content_analysis($text, $format = 'json')
{
    $url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM contentanalysis.analyze WHERE text = "' . $text . '"';

    $characters = array(' ', '=', '"');
    $replacements = array('%20', '%3D', '%22');

    $query = str_replace($characters, $replacements, $query);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "q=$query&format=$format");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

// Text taken from wikipedia
$text1 = 'Computer programming (often shortened to programming or coding) is the process of designing, writing, testing, debugging, and maintaining the source code of computer programs.';
$text2 = 'For the thousands of refugees and migrants landing on its beaches every day Greece Lesbos island is a step to safety and a brighter future in Europe';
$text3 = 'Hurricane Gert was a large tropical cyclone that caused extensive flooding throughout Central America and Mexico in September 1993. It originated over the southwestern Caribbean Sea and briefly attained tropical storm strength before crossing Nicaragua, Honduras, and the Yucatán Peninsula.';

// {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Unknown error","status":"500"}}

$text1 = substr($text1, 0, 120);
echo $text1 . PHP_EOL;
$response1 = yahoo_content_analysis($text1);
echo $response1 . PHP_EOL; // json

echo PHP_EOL;    

$text2 = substr($text2, 0, 116);
echo $text2 . PHP_EOL;
$response2 = yahoo_content_analysis($text2);
echo $response2 . PHP_EOL; // json

echo PHP_EOL;

$text3 = substr($text3, 0, 124);
echo $text3 . PHP_EOL;
$response3 = yahoo_content_analysis($text3);
echo $response3 . PHP_EOL; // json
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Such long strings used to work, so in the absence of being able to find any information online as to why they no longer do, I assume they've made a change that capped the string length for public requests. Possibly, the length for requests authenticated by oauth are longer.

I'm not finding the limit varies by string. This is possibly because you're sanitising the text *after* you're counting the number of characters. After sanitising the string, you're increasing the length, based on how many spaces are in the string that are converted, for example.

Comment: Ah no I'm wrong, I think it was just chance that the strings I was seeing didn't generate the error, it is, as you say, different per string. Perhaps it's that the amount of data that yahoo returns based on the string that generates the error. In which case the yahoo application itself is just plain broken (and apparently, only 2 people have noted it as yet)